# Do service worker cached pages mean the page request will never reach my nginx or server?

Tags: nginx, caching, google-analytics, service-worker, browser-cache

I was looking into the benefits of integrating service workers with an application. As I understand it, a good simplification is that the SW will intercept all network requests from the client and check the cache. If the resource is cached, it will provide that cached resource, if not it will let the request continue as normal.

In the first case however, does this mean that the request will never reach my server? Wouldn't this impact metrics such as site visits or other valuable traffic information? If this is indeed the case then what are some suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends entirely on how you configure your service worker. There are multiple options for caching strategies, some of which will bypass the network request and some won't.

There's a very good breakdown of the different caching methods [here](https://serviceworke.rs/caching-strategies.html)

Comment: If you want metrics about page view, you can set up a dedicate url to call. You can check workbox library analytics plugin